# From Jenkins "sh" to groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way that this jenkins variable with Stdout: true and so on be rewritten in groovy?

```
def result = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo \"$changeString\" | grep -o 'DPDHLPA-[0-9][0-9]*' | sort | uniq").trim()
```

How can this grep but copied?
Echo and sort is understandable for me, but what about the grep and uniq?

Example of output of changeString:

```
[DPDHLPA-26488] Added data-reset-state attribute for smart grid and smart filter
```

Comment: to answer this question correctly you have to provide a sample value of `changeString` variable and expected output.

Comment: Updated comment

Answer (score 0):

```js
def changeString = """
[DPDHLPA-26488] ddd
[DPDHLPA-26488] aaa
[DPDHLPA-26488] bbb
[DPDHLPA-26488] aaa
[DPDHLPA-26489] ccc
[DPDHLPA-26488] ddd
"""

def result = changeString.readLines()
    .collect{it=~/(DPDHLPA-[0-9]+)/}.findAll()
    .collect{it[0][0]}.unique().sort().join('\n')
```

methods to work with List/Collection/Iterable:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html

Comment: How to check if the string matches this regex "DPDHLPA-[0-9][0-9]*" as the grep

Comment: Ah  it worked, but in the end it should only the part "DPDHLPA-2648". Not the whole line